# Java equal method explanation on the following code

Tags: java, object, equals

I have been reading a book called Thinking in Java on Java(I come from C background). I came across the following two set of codes

```
  public class EqualsMethod {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer n1 = new Integer(47);
        Integer n2 = new Integer(47);
        System.out.println(n1.equals(n2));
      }
    } 
//Output: true
```

I understand that this equal method is comparing the reference. But n1 and n2 are two object residing in ´two different "bubble" in the heap. So how come they are equal?

Another example code is

```
class Value {
  int i;
}

    public class EqualsMethod2 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value v1 = new Value();
        Value v2 = new Value();
        v1.i = v2.i = 100;
        System.out.println(v1.equals(v2));
      }
    } /* Output:false


}
```

Why does this give false? Your in depth answer would be much anticipated. Thank you.

Comment: please refrain yourself from asking unnecessary questions, google them first.

Comment: You are not changing the reference of v1 or v2. Both references are pointing to different memory location. The value inside the object does not matter when you are comparing memory location (references) of objects.

Comment: "I understand that this equal method is comparing the reference" -> No, referential comparisons are generally done using `==`, not `equals()` (unless the class hasn't overridden `.equals()`). The objects are equal because the `.equals()` method in the `Integer` class stipulates that if the two objects represent the same number, they are considered equal to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that this equal method is comparing the reference.

Wrong. In the Object class, this method contains a referential comparison, but Integer has it's own implementation, which overrides the one provided by Object.

It compares the values of the two Integers, not their references.

Comment: @Ram, you can refer the implementation of `equal()` method of `Value` class in my answer.

Comment: the part I was missing was that Integer has its own implementation of equal method by overriding it. Thus the equal method that Object uses to compare two object is different than equal class that Integer has it. Probably that is the reason it is suggested to override the equal method. Your answer was short and easy to understand but then again correct me if I understood in a wrong fashion.

Comment: Integer has it's own implementation of equals. In Object it indeed compares references, but in Integer, it compares the actual values, which is why it returns true, even though the references were different. Object is just a base for an Object, actually: since it can't know what to compare on, it compares the references, to check whether it is the exact same Object. For more specific classes, you know exactly what to compare on, so you override the equals method. (Except for Singletons, where a referential comparison is sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `equals` in your custom classes is entirely up to you. If you override it, you decide when two objects of your class are considered equal to each other. If you don't override it, you get the default implementation of `Object` class, which checks if both references refer to the same object (i.e. checks if `v1==v2` in your example, which is false).

Comment: The equals is not in his custom class.

Comment: @Stultuske I know that. I wrote "if you override it". I didn't claim that the OP overrode it.

Comment: You assume it is possible for the OP to override the equals method of the Integer class?

Comment: @Stultuske The Integer class is not a custom class. A custom class is a class you write yourself, like the `Value` class in the question.

Comment: Missed that part, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Root of the issue :

You have not overrriden eqauals and hashCode and then JVM assigns a new hashCode to any object you create in the case of Value class

=================

Solution : 
You will need to define the criteria on which the identities of the value object is measured i.e do the following

1) Override the equals method and specify that the equality is checked over the value of the instance variable i

2) Override Hashcode and use instance variable i for the hashCode comparison

== is used in the equals method in the object class to avoid unnecessary calculation if the two refrences point to the same object and if not go ahead with the calculation and comparisons

public boolean equals(Object anObject)
 {

if (this == anObject) {

return true;

}
        else{

```
  // Do the calculation here to check the identity check 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not override equals method. If you do not override it then it will check if the reference are equal or not and return accordingly.

You can refer [`equals()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method defined in Integer class.

```
System.out.println(n1.equals(n2)) // this prints true because it refers to Integer equals method.
```

Similarly you will have to override it for your Value class like.

```
class Value {
    int i;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Value) {
            Value valObj = (Value) obj;
            if (this.i == valObj.i) {
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Now `System.out.println(v1.equals(v2));` prints **true**.

Comment: You may want to check the api for Integer.

Comment: @Stultuske added reference to equals method of Integer.

Comment: that is actually the one he is using (and asking about). The rest of the answer is not relevant, since it's Integers implementation that matters

Comment: @Stultuske, I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: understood, yes, but a part of the question was blocked on my screen. We were talking about different parts of the question, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is valuable type. So comparing to `Integer` variables performing by comparing their values. Which are equal in your particular case.

Comparing two objects (reference type) performing by comparing the references, which are not equal.

You could write your own comparison logic by overloading the `equals()` method in your class.

Comment: The correct answer is: because Integer contains an override of toString and doesn't use Object's default method that compares by reference.
The OP can not write his own logic in his own class to compare two Integer instances by using the equals method. That can only be done in the integer class.

Answer (score 0):

Integer has the method equals() that compare the value, and your Value class doesn't. It makes the Value class with equals compare the "pointer", and they're different.

If you override the method equals in your class Value comparing the attribute i from the class, it would return true.
For example

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
   return (this.i == ((Value) o).i) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Equals method in all Wrapper classes is overridden by default in java. That's is why first snippet works.
For your own classes, you have to provide an implementation of equals method.

Answer (score 0):

By default the equal method in Java check if the two Object references are the same. You can *@Override* the method, and do what you want. So it is normal that you get False, because the two Object are different.

Answer (score 0):

> So how come they are equal?

**Integer** is an Object. On the other side **int** is a simple type.
Integer's equals() method compare int inside, because it's overriding Object equals() method. int's there has the same value.

> Why does this give false?

Your **Value** class doesn't override equal's method, so then refferences are compared, exactly like when you write v1 == v2. In this case they are different Objects so it's false.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your understanding of equals and == is completely wrong or opposite to what it actually is.

equals() method also checks for reference as == does, there is no difference between both of them unless you override the equals method.
== check for reference equality. For better understanding see Object class source code.

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Why is it working in your case? is because Integer class overrides the equals method in it.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
}
return false;
n
}
```

Now when you use your custom class to check equality what it is doing is basically calling.

```
v1==v2
```

How it can give you true? They both have different memory locations in heap.
If still things are not clear put break points in your code and run it in debug mode.